# error cb() never called! This is an error with npm itself

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I am facing this issue, when cloning one of the repo, I am having a proxy also at the back which is working fine for other repos.

Debug.log file looks like this.

```
73613 silly extract core-js@^3.3.4 extracted to /Users/Development/workspace/star/node_modules/.staging/core-js-762f7d24 (15298ms)
73614 silly extract rxjs@^6.6.2 extracted to /Users/Development/workspace/star/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-d84d800e (10989ms)
73615 silly extract rxjs@^6.6.2 extracted to /Users/Development/workspace/star/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-5e744e4e (10932ms)
73616 silly extract rxjs@^6.6.2 extracted to /Users/Development/workspace/star/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-bba6736e (10810ms)
73617 silly extract rxjs@6.6.3 extracted to /Users/Development/workspace/star/node_modules/.staging/rxjs-050d768d (10271ms)
73618 timing npm Completed in 206111ms
73619 error cb() never called!
73620 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
73621 error <https://npm.community>
```

Solutions Tried:

npm cache clean --force

Delete existing node_modules, delete package-lock.json, and reinstall using - npm i

npm cache verify

npm clean-install